# Is it possible to use System.Web.Routing in Castle Monorail?

Tags: asp.net, castle-monorail, asp.net-routing

Is it possible to use the Microsoft (or Mono) supplied System.Web.Routing instead of the MonoRail routing stuff when building a Castle MonoRail app for ASP.NET?  Any good information on how to implement this as a solution?  Pros and cons?

Comment: For anybody that would like to suggest that an answer to this question is just to adopt the entire ASP.NET MVC stack, I give you Joel Spolsky:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite possible. You should implement ASP.NET's `IRouteHandler` that will look up the route data in the given `RequestContext`, and then hand the data over to MonoRail.

That can be done is several ways. I guess that Server.RewritePath will work, but you can more cleanly lookup the code in two classes of MonoRail, namely `MonorailHttpHandlerFactory` and `RoutingModuleEx`, to figure out how to return set the needed things on the `MonoRailHttpHandler` you'll return from the `IRouteHandler`.

As for problems - it would be very tricky to to the reverse, i.e. generate routes from controller actions.